# Shimano FD-M191 replaced with Shimano FD-M590

Tags: chain, derailleur, shimano, hybrid-bike

just replaced Shimano front derailleur (FD-M191) to FD-M590. And problem appears, on smallest cog chain rubs lightly on left side, and on biggest cog on right side.
Just can't lower derailleur more when chain on smallest cog, cant put derailleur higher when chain on biggest cog. I think just reached limits in both directions, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the data sheets for the FD-M191 and FD-M590, you should be able to run one for another provided the difference between the middle and largest cog is at least 12 teeth.

The first thing to check is if you've [adjusted the front derailleur properly](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustments). Are you using a reasonable gear combination when its rubbing? If so, are you using a 9 speed chain?

Comment: I have SHIMANO FC-M131 Chainset, KMC chain, SHIMANO  RDM310 Rear Derailleur, and FD-M191 Front Derailleur. Find in local shop on internet big clearance, so bought Shimano FD-M590 and Shimano Deore RD-M531 rear Derailleur.Replaced rear Derailleur from altus to deore it works percectly, but front no. Gears combinations are, smallest in front and biggest cog rear, chain rubs left side(it stops when rear on 3 cog) and when chain on biggest cog in front, smallest on rear , chain rub on right side (it not rub when on 6 cog). I have 7 speed cassette.
I dint change chain,  still using 7 gear chain.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Shimano document [SI-6R3FA-002](http://www.shimano-france.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/SI_6R3FA_002/SI-6R3FA-002-ENG_v1_m56577569830673558.pdf), FD-M191 works with the Acera M360 groupset, which is 8 speed, whereas [FD-M590 is a 9 speed component](http://cycle.shimano-eu.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/nl/index/components/trekking_bike/deore_m590/product.-code-FD-M590.-type-.fd_mountain.html).